# WixToolset 3.11 Util:PermissionEx error for createfolder

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am new to Wix installation toolkit and have been trying to create an installer. I am using it as a plugin to VS 2017. This is so far as I have got.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util=" http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

<Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="ProgramDataVendorFolder" Name="ABC">
          <!--This will create the \ProgramData\MyVendor\MyProductName\ folder. -->
          <Directory Id="ProgramDataAppFolder" Name="DEF" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
        </Directory>
    <DirectoryRef Id="ProgramDataAppFolder">
      <Component Id="CmpCreateCommonAppDataFolderWithPermissions" Guid="*" Permanent="yes">
        <CreateFolder>
          <!--This will ensure that everyone gets full permissions to the folder that we create in the ProgramData folder.--> 
          <util:PermissionEx User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />
        </CreateFolder>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

Added a reference to "WixUtilExtension.dll" in the project.

But I get the error

> Error : The CreateFolder element contains an unhandled extension
>   element 'util:PermissionEx'. Please ensure that the extension for
>   elements in the ' http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension'
>   namespace has been provided.

In addition I have also tried using the http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util instead of  http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension

I tried to comment out the code above and then get the error

> The extension
>   'Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Extensions.UtilExtension'
>   contains a defintion for table 'EventManifest' that collides with a
>   previously loaded table definition.  Please remove one of the
>   conflicting extensions or rename one of the tables to avoid the
>   collision.

Could someone please help me out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Missing Reference***: You must have forgotten to add a reference to the
>   **`WixUtilExtension.dll`** file in the WiX installation folder. Please follow the procedure below to add the reference.

***In Visual Studio***:

1. Open your WiX project.
2. Right click **`"References"`** in the right pane => **`Add References...`**
3. Browse to the file, or paste the following (if using standard installation paths)**`C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixUtilExtension.dll`**.
4. Click **`"Add"`** and then **`"OK"`**.

---

> ***WiX Sample Code***: Some [WiX sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130) described here.

---

The most common namespaces to add to the WiX element:

```
 xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" (Burn)
 xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension" (.NET)
 xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension" (IIS)
 xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" (Util)
 xmlns:wixloc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization" (Localization)
```

[IsWiX](https://github.com/iswix-llc) is nice for namespaces and more (screenshot below). It is a free WiX tool from Chris Painter:

[image: IsWiX Namespaces]

Comment: As I mentioned earlier that I had WixUtilExtension.dll as reference.But still removing that file, closing the solution, reopening the solution and adding it again fixed the issue. I am not sure why.                                                                                                              But the common namespaces was a good tip for me. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Great, please set as accepted answer if it solved your problem. These things with references happen. I have seen it myself - those "intermittent problems". Often it can be a reference to a similar but different dll - for example to `WixUIExtension.dll` instead of `WixUtilExtension.dll` or you reference the WiX4 dlls from WiX3 or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You have a leading space in the xmlns:util namespace.  Remove this and things should work OK.